# Calculating Percentages with SUM and Group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create an *Over Time Calculation* based on some set criteria. It goes as follows.

Overtime is posted on any day that is over 8 hrs but an employee has to reach 40 total hrs first and the calculation starts at the 1st day moving forward in the week. The Overtime is calculated based on the  percentage taken of the `SUM` total of the cost codes worked.

First you have to find the percentage of each cost code worked for the entire week per employee id. See Example below

Then each day that is Over 8 hrs you take the time on that code for the day and multiply it by the calculated percentage. At the end of the week the regular hours must total 40hrs if they have gone over 40 for the week.  See below example

```
CREATE TABLE [Totals](
    [Day] nvarchar (10) null,
    [EmployeeID] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CostCode] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [TotalTime] [real] NULL,)

INSERT  Into Totals (day,employeeid, CostCode, TotalTime) VALUES
('1','1234','1', 2),
('1','1234','2', 7.5),
('2','1234','1', 1.5),
('2','1234','2', 8),
('3','1234','1', 1),
('3','1234','2', 6),
('4','1234','1', 2),
('4','1234','2', 8),
('5','1234','1', 2),
('5','1234','2', 8),
('1','4567','1', 2),
('1','4567','2', 8.5),
('2','4567','1', 1.5), 
('2','4567','2', 7.6),
('3','4567','1', 1),
('3','4567','2', 5),
('4','4567','1', 2),
('4','4567','2', 8),
('5','4567','1', 2),
('5','4567','2', 8)
```

To get the percentage of each cost Worked it is the SUM total time of each cost per week / SUM total time  of the entire week

```
   SELECT employeeid,CostCode,SUM(totaltime) As TotalTime ,
   ROUND(SUM(Totaltime) / (select SUM(TotalTime) from Totals where employeeid = '1234') * 100,0) as Percentage
    from Totals WHERE EmployeeID = '1234' group by EmployeeID, CostCode
```

Percentage Calculated for the Week by Cost = 18% worked on Cost 1 and 82% on Cost 2

I would like to take the percentage results for the week and calculate the total time each day in the query

Results Example Day 1: for EmployeeID  1234

```
Day CostCode RegTime OverTime 
 1     1        1.73     .27      
 1     2        6.27    1.23
```

Comment: can you update the expected result in table format

Comment: First - you don't need the inner query for your IN. You can use SUM as a window function `SUM (xxxx) OVER (PARTITION BY yyyy)`. That being said - I'm not clear on how you want to calculate which numbers as percentages?

Comment: First you have to find the percentage of each cost code worked for the entire week per employee id. So in the example above employee 1234 worked 22.666 % of the time on Cost Code 1 and the Remainder on Cost Code 2. Then each day that is Over 8 hrs you take the time on that code for the day and multiply it by the calculated percentage. Hope that clears things up a bit

Comment: I don't see anything that tells what "day" these hours are for.

Comment: How did u gt 22.666 % ? (Emp 1234 - CostCode:1 , TotalTime:8.5 & CostCode:2 , TotalTime:37.5) rgt?

Comment: You have to provide a logic you use to calculate 22.666% At this moment your question is completely unclear. User 1234 worked 2 hrs on Cost 1 and 7.5 hrs on Cost 2. This gives you 9.5 hrs, which means employee worked 1.5 hrs over 8 hrs day: `(9.5-8)/8 = 0.1875`!

Comment: It is the SUM total of each cost  per week. / SUM total of time for the week did the math incorrectly. I will revise above

Comment: BrianMichaels, please check your data as the workings are incorrect. e.g. Person1234 worked 8.5 hrs on 1 and 37.5 hrs on 2 which is 18.5% and 81.5%.  Also simplify the wording of the puzzle. e.g. this sentence has 2 separate bits of logic in it "Overtime is posted on any day that is over 8 hrs but an employee has to reach 40 total hrs first and the calculation starts at the 1st day moving forward in the week. " Also you had 2hours on code 1 for day 1 which went to 1.2 and .34 where is the other .46 of the day gone? None of your example is adding up.

Comment: Have you reed the answers? Is there any adequate for your question? Please show by what formula you get this results?

Comment: what do you mean by "has to reach 40 total hrs first"? 
If I work 10 hours per day (Mon-Fri), the "extra" two hours I put daily doesn't count until I "reach 40 total hrs first", so the actual over time is the only two hours accrued on Fri?

Answer (score 2):

After editing i get your result, try this:

```
select calc.*
--select [day], CostCode, EmployeeID
--, CPr * DayEmpRT RegTime_old
, TotalTime - CPr * DayEmpOT RegTime
, CPr * DayEmpOT OverTime
from ( 
  select Agr.*
  --, round(EmpC1T / EmpT, 2) C1Pr
  --, round(1 - (EmpC1T / EmpT), 2) C2Pr
  , round(EmpCT / EmpT, 2) CPr
  , case when DayEmpT > 8 then 8 else DayEmpT end DayEmpRT
  , case when DayEmpT > 8 then DayEmpT - 8 else 0 end DayEmpOT
  from (
    select Totals.*
    , SUM(TotalTime) over (partition by EmployeeID, [day]) DayEmpT
    --, SUM(case when CostCode = 1 then TotalTime end) over (partition by EmployeeID) EmpC1T
    , SUM(TotalTime) over (partition by EmployeeID, CostCode) EmpCT
    , SUM(TotalTime) over (partition by EmployeeID) EmpT
    from Totals
    WHERE EmployeeID = '1234' ) Agr ) calc
order by 1,2,3
```

here is simplest way to calculate this:

```
select calc.*
, TotalTime * pr4R RegTime
, TotalTime * pr4O OverTime
from(
  select Agr.*
  , case when EmpT > 40 then round(40/EmpT, 2) else 1 end pr4R
  , case when EmpT > 40 then round(1 - 40/EmpT, 2) else 1 end pr4O
  from (
    select Totals.*
    , SUM(TotalTime) over (partition by EmployeeID) EmpT
    from Totals
    WHERE EmployeeID = '1234' ) Agr ) calc
```

but be watch on day 3, because there is only 7h. 
The 1st query calculate days separately and live day 3.
The 2nd query scale all hours.
it could be another one, that calculate all emp rows but scale separatly RegTime and OverTime, with exception on day where is no 8h and increment it to 8h from OverTime.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get started...

```
-- % based on hours worked for each code on a DAILY basis (The original 21% in the question was based on this)
SELECT
T.EmployeeId,
T.Day,
T.CostCode,
T.TotalTime,
CAST(100.0 * T.TotalTime / X.DailyHours AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS PercentageWorked
FROM #Totals T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
    EmployeeId,
    Day,
    SUM(TotalTime) AS DailyHours
    FROM #Totals
    GROUP BY EmployeeId, Day
) X ON X.EmployeeId = T.EmployeeId AND X.Day = T.Day


-- % based on hours worked for each code on a WEEKLY basis (The revised question)
SELECT
T.EmployeeId,
T.CostCode,
SUM(T.TotalTime) AS TotalTime,
CAST(100.0 * SUM(T.TotalTime) / X.WeeklyHours AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS PercentageWorked
FROM #Totals T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
    EmployeeId,
    SUM(TotalTime) AS WeeklyHours
    FROM #Totals
    GROUP BY EmployeeId
) X ON X.EmployeeId = T.EmployeeId 
GROUP BY 
T.EmployeeId,
T.CostCode, 
X.WeeklyHours
```